# ionic app with firebase throws cors error on authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

i am built an ionic app and added angular fire authentication. while trying to use createUserWithEmailAndPassword it fails with below error. I think i need to somewhere allow all type of urls but not sure where?

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyDpxa6uWUjzrD1FlTtLaMpxSg2ihRDyMH8. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
```

My app.module.ts

```
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "trykubby-1.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://trykubby-1-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "trykubby-1",
  storageBucket: "trykubby-1.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxx"

};


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
    provideDatabase(() => {
      const database = getDatabase();
      return database;
    }),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      return auth;
    }),
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ]
})
```

my service code is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private auth: Auth) { }

  // Register user with email/password
  registerUser(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password);
  }
}
```

Where do i set the cors to * to allow any origin?